# Ubuntu 21.04 hangs at "loading initial ramdisk" after kernel update with LUKS

Tags: ubuntu, linux-kernel, luks, initrd, ramdisk

I've reproduced this twice from a fresh install - the setup initially works fine, but when a kernel update is applied, the system hangs on reboot. Selecting the older kernel I have available from GRUB works fine.

System details:

- XPS 13 9380
- i5-8265U
- BIOS version 1.15.0
- Microcode version reported as "0xea".  Output of apt list --installed | grep microcode:
  intel-microcode/hirsute-updates,hirsute-security,now 3.20210608.0ubuntu0.21.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
- Secure Boot is, I believe, set to audit mode.
- Ubuntu hirsute (as mentioned)
- Installed on a LUKS partition from LiveUSB
- Currently on 5.11.0-37-generic but I've reproduced with older 5.11 kernels as well. Definitely seems to be the *change* in kernel version rather than the version itself. 5.11.0-36-generic boots with no unusual GRUB options required.

GRUB settings I've tried that **definitely do not work**:

- dis_ucode_ldr and mitigations=off (together or separately);
- nomodeset
- removing quiet splash
- recovery
- debug (no change in output)
- any form of echo after the line "initrd /initrd.img-5.11.0-37-generic"

And all permutations thereof.

lsinitramfs of both initrd.img and initrd.img.old (that I can boot off of) files doesn't pop up any obvious candidates.

It seems to likely be either microcode or cryptsetup-related, but since debug gives nothing, and dmesg presumably reports a normal boot once I boot with 36, I'm slightly at a loss.

Any thoughts? There seem to be related bugs but nothing that exactly reproduces.

Answer (score 6):

Solution: use

```
MODULES=dep
```

in the `/etc/initramfs-tools/initramfs.conf`.

And regenerate with (replace `5.11.0-37-generic` with the kernel version you are using):

```
update-initramfs -c -k  5.11.0-37-generic
```

---

I've hit the same issue as the OP. After an update and a reboot a few days ago, the system hangs on "Loading initial ramdisk..." and no other output.

My hardware is almost identical but for the CPU: i7-8565U.
Same software configuration as listed in the OP.

[Another post](https://ubuntu.forumming.com/question/13311/ubuntu-20-04-21-04-stuck-in-grub-after-encryption) suggests the following:

> The problem originates from large `initrd.img` files (~100MB) generated with `MODULES=most` that can't be loaded due to size limitations. This can be solved by switching to `MODULES=dep` which generates `initrd.img` files of approximately 55MB.

Answer (score 3):

I believe I hit this issue today as well and it took me a good few hours to resolve. The resolution was to rebuild the boot image, which was ~160MB and likely too large (as described by Sorin). However the process to do so took a bit of figuring out.

**Machine**

- Dell XPS 9550
- Ubuntu 20.04
- UEFI Boot partition: `nvme0n1p2`
- LUKS encrypted primary partition: `nvme0n1p3`

**Symptoms**

On boot, instead of the LUKS password prompt I was greeted with the grub menu. Choosing `Ubuntu` lead to a blank screen. Attempting to boot in recovery mode would get as far as "loading initial ramdisk" before freezing. As with Bereded (OP), I tried a whole range of GRUB config flags and BIOS settings to no avail.

**Solution**

We need to boot from USB, change the initramfs-tools config, then rebuild the `initrd.img`.

1. Boot from a live USB
2. Decrypt/unlock the primary partition (replace `nvme0n1p3` with your encrypted partition name)

   ```
   sudo cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/nvme0n1p3 nvme0n1p3_crypt
   ```
3. Mount the encrypted partition to `/mnt`, the boot partition to `/mnt/boot`, then chroot `/mnt`

   ```bash
   vgscan --mknodes
   vgchange -ay
   sudo mount /dev/mapper/vgubuntu-root /mnt # may be named ubuntu--vg-root depending on your system
   sudo mount /dev/nvme0n1p2 /mnt/boot  # replace nvme0n1p2 with your boot partition
   for i in /dev /dev/pts /proc /sys /run; do sudo mount -B $i /mnt$i; done
   sudo chroot /mnt
   ```
4. From the chroot shell, open and edit `/etc/initramfs-tools/initramfs.conf`, set:

   ```
   MODULES=dep
   ```
5. Take a backup of your current/latest `initrd.img`. e.g

   ```
   mv /boot/initrd.img-5.13.0-44-generic /boot/initrd.img-5.13.0-44-generic.bak
   ```
6. Rebuild the image (replace with current kernel version)

   ```
   update-initramfs -c -k 5.13.0-44-generic
   ```
7. Update grub

   ```
   update-grub
   ```
8. Exit and reboot, you should now be able to boot from the rebuilt image

**Troubleshooting**

The name you give the mapped device when calling `cryptsetup luksOpen` is important - it should match the volume name configured in your crypttab (which you can't see yet because you haven't unlocked/mounted the partition). By convention, it should be `<device_name>_crypt`. If this is incorrect, you'll get the following warning when running `update-initramfs`.

```
cryptsetup: WARNING: target '<Device UUID>' not found in /etc/crypttab
```

**Resources**

- https://linoxide.com/fixing-broken-initrd-image-linux/
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/844132/how-to-repair-boot-on-luks-encrypted-harddrive

Comment: Your answer, in combination with Sorin, helped me fix the issue. I could boot into recovery mode, so I didn't have to use a live USB. For anyone else with this problem, make sure you run **BOTH** ```sudo update-initramfs -c -k <kernal version>``` and ```sudo update-grub```

Answer (score 0):

Typing the (correct) LUKS password and confirming with enter - as if the dm-crypt promt were there - resulted in a regular boot, for me.

(have experienced this on a current Debian (netinstall) as well as on Alpine Linux)